# trigger azure databricks notebook or job by terraform or powershell

Tags: terraform, azure-databricks, jobs, terraform-provider-databricks, databricks-workflows

I am trying to automate the process of azure databricks creation along with cluster, notebook and job and to run the notebook, by terraform. The code that I have, creates the above resources. But I am not able to run the notebook or the job by terraform.

```
provider "databricks" {
    azure_workspace_resource_id = azurerm_databricks_workspace.example.id
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}
resource "azurerm_databricks_workspace" "example" {
  name                = "databricks-test"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku                 = "standard"

}
resource "databricks_cluster" "shared_autoscaling" {
  cluster_name            = "Autoscaling-Cluster"
  spark_version           = "10.5.x-scala2.12"
  node_type_id            = "Standard_DS3_v2"
  autotermination_minutes = 15
  autoscale {
    min_workers = 1
    max_workers = 3
  }  
  library {
    maven {
      coordinates = "com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.12:2.3.18"
    }
  }
  library {
    maven {
      coordinates = "com.microsoft.azure:azure-event-hubs-reactive_2.12:0.1.0"
    }
  }
}
resource "databricks_notebook" "notebook" {
  path = "/IOT_notebook"
  language = "PYTHON"
  format = "SOURCE"
  source = "./IOT_notebook.dbc"
}
resource "databricks_job" "myjob5" {
    name = "Featurization2"
    timeout_seconds = 3600
    max_retries = 1
    max_concurrent_runs = 1
    existing_cluster_id = databricks_cluster.shared_autoscaling.id

    notebook_task {
        notebook_path = databricks_notebook.notebook.path
        //base_parameters = var.resource_group_name
        
    }
}
```

I am not able to find any code related to running the notebook or the job, neither in terraform nor in powershell. I want to know if it is possible to do it through a script or not.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The triggering of the job isn't a responsibility of the Terraform - it takes care that all objects are created & their state is matching to what is declared, but triggering is an *activity*, not the *final state*. So although technically you can trigger the job from terraform using the local resource + for, example, `curl`, it's better to use something else to actually trigger that job.

You can trigger job multiple ways using the job ID returned by Terraform:

- Using the [REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsRunNow) - just use something like `curl`
- Using the [databricks-cli](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/jobs-cli.html): `databricks jobs run-now --job-id <job-id>`
- for Powershell, there is a [DatabricksPS](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/DatabricksPS/1.9.9.11) package that includes the `Start-DatabricksJob` function that simplifies execution of existing jobs

Comment: thank you so much @alex ott for your suggestions. It really helped to resolve my issues.